# Workflow stuck in "Started" and never completes

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-manager

I have a SharePoint 2016 workflow that only needs to kick off an email to a group of users and it is stuck in a "Started" state and never completes/sends out the emails.

The error I receive in the information is:

"Activity in progress

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to http://server_name/subsite/subsite/_api/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail Correlation Id: 1d790a92-64f2-a504-b6a1-2520a9935e35 Instance Id: 455412e3-7a9a-42d0-8aa9-ef65daeca821

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. 
Retry now"

I had briefly resolved this issue previously by doing the troubleshooting in step 1 below, but it appears to have reverted the settings at some point.

Troubleshooting I've tried:

1. Added the XML code to allow the workflow to access the correct permissions, and added the App Step container to the workflow as [Microsoft suggests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo).
2. On the server I changed the "Security Token Service" app pool's "Load User Profile" setting was set to true, recycled the app pool, and restarted IIS.
3. I made sure the OU with the security groups I was using are sync'd via the User Profile sync. This runs every night on the server to perform a full sync of AD to SharePoint.

I'm not seeing any errors in the Event Viewer on the server either.